# Trouble with JOGL and Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, opengl, jogl

I'm new to OpenGL in Java, and Java in general. I am following a textbook and trying to create my first window. However, when I run my code, I get the error that "package com.jogamp.opengl does not exist". I have added the .JAR files to my project's reference libraries [as shown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMbjh.png)

My code reads:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import static com.jogamp.opengl.GL4.*;
import com.jogamp.opengl.*;
import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;

public class Code extends JFrame implements GLEventListener {
private GLCanvas myCanvas;

public Code() {
    setTitle("Chapter 2 - program 1");
    setSize(600, 400);
    setLocation(200, 200);
    myCanvas = new GLCanvas();
    myCanvas.addGLEventListener(this);
    this.add(myCanvas);
    this.setVisible(true);
}

public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    GL4 gl = (GL4) GLContext.getCurrentGL();
    gl.glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Code();
}

public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
}

public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
}

public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
}
}
```

Any advice would be great - I'm guessing it is some simple step I've missed, but I've gone over the section in the book a couple of times now so I'm nto sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add jogamp-fat.jar into the classpath. Please rather ask your JOGL specific questions on the official JogAmp forum as only a very few JOGL maintainers and users come on StackOverflow. Please ensure that you use at least JOGL 2.3.2. The namespace used in the JAR(s) must match with the namespace used in your source code above. Moreover, you must include the necessary JAR(s) not only when you compile but when you run your project too.

I don't know how VisualStudio Code works, these are the instructions for other major Java IDEs: https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php?title=Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I'll make sure to ask any future questions over on the JogAmp Forum.